# Iterate and invoke a list of methods

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

Let say I have 2 classes:

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Contact contact;
    //getter & setter
}

public class Contact
{
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    //getter & setter
}
```

With the classes above, I want to create 2 instances of `Person` class, with different field value. Then I want to compare some fields of 2 objects with their getter function, but I don't want to compare all fields.

For example, I want to compare the field `name` and `phone`, then I will store this 2 getter method to a list like something below:

```
List<WhatShouldBeTheDataType> funcList = new ArrayList<>();
funcList.add(MyClass::getName);
funcList.add(MyClass::getContact::getPhone) //I know this won't work, what should be the solution?
```

then loop through the `funcList`, pass the 2 objects I want to compare into the function, if the value not same, write something into the database. This can be easily done with ordinary `if...else...` way, but is it possible to do in Java 8 way?

Below is what I want to achieve in `if...else...` way:

```
if(person1.getName() != person2.getName())
{
    //message format basically is: "fieldName + value of object 1 + value of object 2"
    log.append("Name is different: " + person1.getName() + ", " + person2.getName());

}
if(person1.getContact.getPhone() != person2.getContact().getPhone())
{
    log.append("Phone is different: " + person1.getContact.getPhone() + ", " + person2.getContact.getPhone());
}
//other if to compare other fields
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `Person` and `MyClass` refer to the same thing in your question.

You need a `Function<Person,String>`, since your functions accept a `Person` instance and return a `String`:

```
List<Function<Person,String>> funcList = new ArrayList<>();
funcList.add(Person::getName);
funcList.add(p -> p.getContact().getPhone());
```

For the second function, you can't use a method reference, but you can use a lambda expression instead.

Given an instance of `Person`, you can apply your functions as follows:

```
Person instance = ...;
for (Function<Person,String> func : funcList) {
    String value = func.apply(instance);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but what about the latter part of my question? which is how to compare 2 objects with functions stored in `funcList`?

Comment: @Newbie You can pass these functions to `Comparators.comparing` to obtain an instance of `Comprator<Person>`. Then you can use that `Comparator`'s `compare` method directly, or pass the `Comparator` to other methods (for example, pass it to `Collections.sort()`, to sort a `List<Person>`).

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use a list of functions (as suggested in Eran's answer), using comparators directly is probably more appropriate for your use case.

You can alternatively use a chain of comparators, and then use the result of `compare`:

```
Comparator<Person> comparators = Comparator.comparing((Person p) -> p.getName())
        .thenComparing((Person p) -> p.getContact().getPhone());

Person p1 = null, p2 = null;
if(0 != comparators.compare(person1, person2)) {
    //p1 and p2 are different
}
```

Even simpler (and more natural, in my opinion), is overriding `equals` in `Person`, and checking `if(!person1.equals(person2))`

---

**Edit (after update of the question):**

Here's a version built on a function list, dynamically generating the `log` content by adding a field name list:

```
List<Function<Person, String>> functions = 
        Arrays.asList(Person::getName, p -> p.getContact().getPhone());
List<String> fieldNames = Arrays.asList("Name", "Phone");

IntStream.range(0, functions.size())
        .filter(i -> functions.get(i).apply(person1)
                      .compareTo(functions.get(i).apply(person2)) != 0)
        .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%s is different: %s, %s", 
                            fieldNames.get(i),
                            functions.get(i).apply(person1), 
                            functions.get(i).apply(person2)))
        .forEach(log::append);
```

This rather takes advantage of the fact that `String` is already comparable, and avoids creating comparators altogether.

Comment: Hi, thank you for sharing your idea, but I want to do a task on each data unmatch, see my updated question.

Comment: @Newbie Edited. That changes it slightly.

Answer (score 1):

to complete Eran's code:

```
boolean isEqual(Person person1, Person person2){
    for (Function<Person,String> function:functionList) {
        if (!function.apply(person1).equals(function.apply(person2))) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

then use the returned boolean to check and update your database.